# Accessing Dictionary keys programmatically

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an array and a Dictionary and I would like to run some for loops to see if the elements in the array are equal to each of the keys in the Dictionary.

Is there a way to do this using objective-c?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your array and dictionary?

Comment: It is possible to compare objects in arrays with objects in dictionaries, yes. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableSet *intersection = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
[intersection addObjectsFromArray:array];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[dictionary allKeys]]];
```

`intersection` contains a set of the objects that exists both as keys in your dictionary and in your array.